# Разделение данных на 3 выборки

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, sklearn

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как разбить данные на обучающую, валидационную и тестовую выборки в пропорции 60:20:20, сейчас получается так:

```
df_train, df_test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, random_state=12345)
features_val, features_test, target_val, target_test = \
    train_test_split(features, target, test_size=0.25, random_state=12345)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну, например, вот так:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],'B':[11,23,45,67,89,32,43,54,65,76]})
df_train, df_test1 =train_test_split(df, test_size=0.4, random_state=42)
df_test, df_val=train_test_split(df_test1, test_size=0.5, random_state=42)
print(df_train)
print(df_test)
print(df_val)
```

Результат:

```
   A   B
7  7  54
2  2  45
9  9  76
4  4  89
3  3  67
6  6  43

   A   B
8  8  65
5  5  32

   A   B
1  1  23
0  0  11
```

Как видите -  пропорция 60:20:20, как просили.

Answer (score 1):

**Задача для произвольных размеров выборок**

Заданы размеры в процентах для тренировочной и валидационной выборки, например:

```
train_size = 60
valid_size = 20
```

Тестовую выборку, в таком случае, мы получим из того куска датасета, который останется от тренировочной и валидационной: `test_size = 100 - train_size - valid_size`.

**Решение**

Используем метод `numpy.split()`. Он принимает на вход датафрейм и пороги срезов. Возвращает *разрезанные* куски датафрейма. Предварительно, данные в датафрейме требуется перемешать с помощью `pandas.DataFrame.sample()`

Итак:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def triple_split(data, t_size, v_size):
    return np.split(
        data.sample(frac=1, random_state=123),
        [int(len(data)*t_size/100),
         int(len(data)*(t_size+v_size)/100)]
    )

dic = {
    'A': np.random.randint(10, 99, 20),
    'B': np.random.randint(10, 99, 20),
    'C': np.random.randint(10,99, 20)
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic)

print(df)

train_size = 60
val_size = 20

train, valid, test = triple_split(df, train_size, val_size)
print(train)
print(valid)
print(test)
```

**Важно**

Метод `train_test_split()` опционально поддерживает параметр стратификации, который отвечает за распределение выборки по классам. Если он будет необходим - тогда останется только применять `train_test_split()` два раза, как указано в соседнем ответе.